# Laravel Sanctum - 419 CSRF token mismatch using a Vue SPA

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, cookies

There are loads of posts around the Internet related to this so I apologise if I've missed the answer here, but I seem to be going round in circles even after looking at all the existing answers. I'm clearly overlooking something.

I have a Laravel app which was recently upgraded from 6 to 8 which is being served locally under `api.company-name.local`. I also have a separate Vue front-end SPA being served under `app.company-name.local:8080`. I seem to get a successful response after getting the cookie, however when I hit my login endpoint I get a `419 - CSRF Token Mismatch` response.

**Setup**

The Laravel app sits containerised locally with Docker, front-end simply being served up with `npm run serve` and I have entries in my hosts file for:

```
127.0.0.1    api.company-name.local
127.0.0.1    app.company-name.local
```

**Front-End**

I make a request to `api.company-name.local/sanctum/csrf-cookie` from within the front-end app which returns a 204 response, and then make a POST request to my login endpoint to authenticate the user.

```js
const login = async () => {
  await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
      .then(() => {
            axios.post('/loginUser', {
                username: 'my-username',
                password: 'my-password',
            })
      })
}
```

Observing the login POST request, I can see two cookies being sent in the request headers.

In my `main.ts` file I have configured the following axios defaults:

```js
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://api.my-company.local'
```

**Back-End**

I have updated my `.env` file to the following:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=app.company-name.local (have also tried .company-name.local)
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=app.company-name.local:8080
```

I have added the appropriate middleware to the kernel:

```php
'api' => [
    \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

My `cors.php` file is updated with these details:

```php
'paths' => [
    'api/*',
    'sanctum/csrf-cookie',
    '/loginUser',
    '/logout',
],

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

When the user hits that login endpoint they'll hit this particular route setup, which uses the web middleware:

```php
Route::group([
    'module' => 'Users',
    'middleware' => ['web'],
], function () {
    Route::post('/loginUser', 'UsersController@login');
});
```

It doesn't seem to matter what I change here, I still end up with the 419 so I'm missing something here. Can anyone shed any light on what the problem could be?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: It does nolt look like. I made it work but not within a docker container